# Passing multiple values to same column in the lambda query C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, icollection

Hello I am trying to create a query where in the where clause i need to pass multiple values to the same column and i have built a query using string builder.

My actual Lambda query was

```
 crentitiesbkp.Filter = obj =>
 {
      SPFetchCREntity entity = obj as SPFetchCREntity;
      return obj.ToString() != null && entity.SW_Version==getmuid;
 };
```

Here i changed the entity.SW_Version==getmuid like this

```
crentitiesbkp.Filter = obj =>
{
      SPFetchCREntity entity = obj as SPFetchCREntity;
      return obj.ToString() != null + cquery.ToString();
};
```

so the cquery is built and looks like this

```
&& entity.SW_Version=="TEST" && entity.SW_Version=="Result"
```

But its not filtering as per the query. Is this because this is passed as string ?

The cquery is built like this

```
foreach (var objj in storemuid)
{     
    cquery.Append(" && entity.SW_Version ==" +"\""+ objj.Value + "\"");        
}
```

Comment: You can not use && for the same column. how can the same column have 2 values at the same time? Try to use || Like....... && (entity.SW_Version=="TEST" || entity.SW_Version=="Result")

Comment: `obj.ToString() != null` will never be true. If `obj` is null, this will throw. What query are you trying to perform? What is `Filter`? Most likely it's far easier to do what you want with proper a proper LINQ query, eg `myObjects.OfType<SPFetchCREntity>().Where(myEntity=>myEntity.SQ_Version == something)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am trying to do filter on IcollectionView.

Comment: @SamKing you forgot to mention that in the question. As it is, it doesn't make any sense. The function is *still* meaningless. Besides, you *don't* need it at all to handle selection in WPF. Just bind your control to the proper properties of your ViewModel

Comment: @SamKing for example, bind your control's `Items` property to any collection property on your control. Strongly typed lists are better, eg `T[]` , `List<T>` or `ObservableCollection<T>`. Add a property to *your viewmodel* with the current selection and bind `SelectedItem` to it

Comment: From Ioan-Alexandru Taharu : `the cquery && entity.SW_Version=="TEST" && entity.SW_Version=="Result" will always return false, so you may want to use || instead of &&`

Comment: The filter predicate is supposed to evaulate the properties of the object and return a bool. cquery is just a simple string that means nothing in this context.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this scenario by using dictionary

```
   Dictionary<string, List<SPFetchCREntity>> objDic = new Dictionary<string, List<SPFetchCREntity>>();
        List<SPFetchCREntity> sp = new List<SPFetchCREntity>();
        foreach (string str in objDic.Keys)
        {
            sp.AddRange(objDic[str]);
        }


       CRmappings2 = new ObservableCollection<SPFetchCREntity>(sp.ToList());
        crentitiesbkp = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(CRmappings2);

    }
```

So now based on my checkbox selection i remove and add values from dictionary which works perfect for me now. This can be of any help to starter programmers like me .